# What is the upside of using `tf.nn.rnn` instead of `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

What is the upside of using [`tf.nn.rnn`](https://web.archive.org/web/20170220232722/https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/nn/recurrent_neural_networks#rnn) instead of [`tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`](https://web.archive.org/web/20170220232722/https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/nn/recurrent_neural_networks#dynamic_rnn)?

The [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20170220232722/https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/nn/recurrent_neural_networks#dynamic_rnn)  says :

> [`dynamic_rnn`] is functionally identical to the function `rnn` above, but performs fully dynamic unrolling of inputs.

Is there any case where one might prefer to use `tf.nn.rnn` instead of `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`?