# What is the equivalent of tf.nn.rnn in new versions of TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I used to create the RNN network, in version 0.8 of TensorFlow, using:

```
from tensorflow.python.ops import rnn

# Define a lstm cell with tensorflow
lstm_cell = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0)

# Get lstm cell output
outputs, states = rnn.rnn(cell=lstm_cell, inputs=x, dtype=tf.float32)
```

`rnn.rnn()` is not available anymore, and it sounds it has been moved to `tf.contrib`. What is the exact code to create RNN network out of a `BasicLSTMCell`?

Or, in the case that I have an stacked LSTM,

```
lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_size, forget_bias=0.0)
stacked_lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell] * num_layers)
outputs, new_state =  tf.nn.rnn(stacked_lstm, inputs, initial_state=_initial_state)
```

What is the replacement for `tf.nn.rnn` in new versions of TensorFlow?

Comment: Have you tried the [tf_upgrade.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/compatibility) script?

Answer (score 13):

`tf.nn.rnn` is equivalent to [`tf.nn.static_rnn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/static_rnn).

Note: before [version 1.2 of TensorFlow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/RELEASE.md#release-120), the *namespace* `tf.nn.static_rnn` did not exist, but only [`tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/api_docs/python/) (which is now an *alias* for `tf.nn.static_rnn`).

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`](https://web.archive.org/web/20170227234909/https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn).

FYI: [What is the upside of using `tf.nn.rnn` instead of `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42356027/395857)

Comment: This does not answer the question. You should remove this answer or make it just a comment under the original question.

Comment: @nbro why doesn't it answer the question?

Comment: The question is: **What is the replacement for tf.nn.rnn in new versions of TensorFlow?**.

Comment: @nbro and my answer is "You should use [`tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`](https://web.archive.org/web/20170227234909/https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn).".

Comment: But your answer is to a question like "Should I use dynamic or static RNNs in TF?" or  "Should I use dynamic RNNs?".

Comment: The OP only wanted to know about the equivalent function, in case it is still not clear to you.

Comment: @nbro  tf.nn.dynamic_rnn is a valid answer to "What is the equivalent of tf.nn.rnn in new versions of TensorFlow?".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174611/discussion-between-nbro-and-franck-dernoncourt).