# TensorFLow: tf.contrib.rnn module object is not callable

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to run a tutorial (http://r2rt.com/recurrent-neural-networks-in-tensorflow-ii.html) and have some issue with modules that have moved.

I researched a bit and found that some classes have moved and fixed:

```
tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(state_size)
```

to

```
 tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(state_size)   (that should be correct right?)
```

This works now.

However, I have this function I can't seem to fix:

```
rnn_outputs, final_state = tf.nn.rnn(cell, rnn_inputs, initial_state=init_state)
--> as expected, says: module 'tensorflow.python.ops.nn' has no attribute 'rnn'
```

So I tried:

```
rnn_outputs, final_state = tf.contrib.rnn(cell, rnn_inputs, initial_state=init_state)
```

But that says: 'module' object is not callable

I am using python3 (tried 2 as well), with a fresh installed TensorFlow 1.0.0 through pip3.

I tried looking at the API, but it's not making much sense to me, as I am still going through the tutorial to try to understand what is happening. I would think maybe the arguments have changed, or maybe this is in a sub-function now? https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the equivalent of the rnn() in TensorFLow r 1.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42497216/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-rnn-in-tensorflow-r-1-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found (and ran) the [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/migration) update script on my data.

To fix the remaining errors, just changed tf.nn.rnn_cell. to tf.contrib.rnn and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

Tensor flow has some documentation here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/contrib.rnn

The rnn is part of the contrib module. So if you change it to tf.contrib.rnn is a good step forward but there is an error:
    TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

In the documentation we have several options for recurrent NN:

```
tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn
tf.contrib.rnn.static_state_saving_rnn
tf.contrib.rnn.static_bidirectional_rnn
tf.contrib.rnn.stack_bidirectional_dynamic_rnn
```

For me,

```
tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn
```

worked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is important how you import it. Do like this:

```
from tensorflow.python.ops import rnn, rnn_cell
```

And then use the following:

```
cell = rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(state_size)

rnn_outputs, final_state = rnn.rnn(cell, rnn_inputs, initial_state=init_state)
```

I Use it this way with LSTM cell and it works :)

Comment: Unfortunately that last import (rnn_cell) does not work:    from tensorflow.python.ops import rnn, rnn_cell
ImportError: cannot import name 'rnn_cell'

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I searched on the internet, they say maybe you have to upgrade or downgrade tensorflow. They say they use version 0.8.0, but I will also check mine

Comment: Ok, that can't be it... I have 0.10.0