# How do I change the following code in Tensorflow API r1.0?

Tags: tensorflow

I've upgraded my tensorflow from 0.12 to 1.0. As a result of that, I've met the error code... I try the solving the error, but I can't find the solution. 
I wish your knowledge and experience associated with this to be shared. Thank you.

```
self._initial_state = lstm_cell.zero_state(self.batch_size, tf.float32)
inputs = [tf.squeeze(input_, [1]) for input_ in tf.split(axis=1, num_or_size_splits=4, value=pooled_concat)]

#previous code(v.0.11) : 
self._initial_state = lstm_cell.zero_state(self.batch_size, tf.float32)
inputs = [tf.squeeze(input_, [1]) for input_ in tf.split(1, reduced, pooled_concat)] 


# -------- following code comes out the error--------- 
outputs, state = tf.nn.rnn(lstm_cell, inputs, initial_state=self._initial_state, sequence_length=self.real_len) 

# Above code creates a recurrent neural network specified by RNNCell cell in api 0.11. 
# tf.nn.rnn(cell, inputs, initial_state=None, dtype=None, sequence_length=None, scope=None) 

#---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the equivalent of the rnn() in TensorFLow r 1.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42497216/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-rnn-in-tensorflow-r-1-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
outputs, state = tf.nn.rnn(lstm_cell, inputs, initial_state=self._initial_state, sequence_length=self.real_len)
```

Should be (now, in TF 1.0):

```
outputs, state = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cell, inputs, initial_state=self._initial_state, sequence_length=self.real_len)
```

Due to nn.rnn has been moved to tf.contrib

Answer (score 1):

As of version 1.0 of the API `tf.nn.rnn` was removed. Try using [`tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn). Notice however, that this method expects `inputs` to be a tensor and not a list of tensors (See linked documentation), so you will have to change a bit the way you create your `inputs` variable.